# Bilinear interpolation for retrieving a pixel rectangle in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, interpolation, linear-interpolation, bilinear-interpolation

This problem comes from function [`getRectSubPix_8u32f`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/808ba552c532408bddd5fe51784cf4209296448a/modules/imgproc/src/samplers.cpp#L219-L262) in OpenCV. Basically, the target is to interpolate following pixel's intensity(denote as `I(a,b)`): 
[image]

but what puzzled me was the code snippet:

```
    float a = center.x - ip.x;
    float b = center.y - ip.y;
    a = MAX(a,0.0001f);
```

Why manually setting a floor `0.0001` here? To my understanding, intensity of `p` should be `I(0,0)` if `p` is exactly located at `(0,0)`. So what is the material thought here? And why not set a floor for `b`?

Comment: they divide by `a` when calculating `s` so `a` must not be `0`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, if the `div-by-zero` is the problem, then it should have been `MAX(a,1.0f)`, as division by 1 would return what we started from. With `0.0001f`, we get something `10000 times` larger now.

Comment: @JoeyMallone not necessarily, the code is doing some kind of funky interpolation. the value of `s` isn't used directly and is used to calculate `prev` instead.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Hi,  is it viable to replace `0.0001` with [`FLT_EPSILON`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/)?because I think it will lessen the discrepancy as much as possible.

Comment: No idea, you are probably better off asking on the OpenCV developer mailing lists, I'm just guessing based on looking at the code